# Regex to extract all window.location occurences from a HTML document using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

How to extract all the window.location occurrences in PHP? I am reading a series of URLs using cURL, storing its HTML content as a string and want to match all the window.location occurrences and output them separately. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. TIA.

```
$str = 'window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        window.location.assign("http://www.example.com");
        window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
        self.location = "http://www.example.com";
        top.location = "http://www.example.com";
        ';
preg_match('(window\\.location*)', $str,$result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You need `preg_match_all` instead of just `preg_match`.

Comment: do you want to display the url i.e., `http://www.example.com` or just `window.location`?

Comment: Only one of your examples has just `window.location`. Are all of those URLs suppose to be found? Maybe `window\.location\h*=\h*("|')(.*?)\1`... https://regex101.com/r/PXYyOY/1 or update the question with what results should be.

Comment: Better splitt the string by line-breaks into an array and regex each line. This will not work `'(window\\.location*)'` It grabs a part from the first occurence till the end of the file.

Comment: @aimee both. Imagine that $str has several lines of HTML code and I need to extract only 'window.location' from that

Comment: @devel0pp3r It not that easy, what if the script uses `'` single-quotes instead of `"` double-quotes?

Comment: @chris85, All of the window.location.* needs to be found

Comment: So `self.location` and `top.location` should not be found?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ZdNmLh, you need to use `preg_match_all` and replace `*` with `.*`

Comment: `window.location` is not equal to `self.location` or `top.location`, why dont you just match all URL's you can find?

Comment: Let me be more precise on my question. I have to read 4 or 5 URLs and find all javascript redirects from their HTML's. So I was starting with these @chris85

Comment: Okay, so you want all URLs, regex was just for the first 4? Maybe this is what you want, https://regex101.com/r/PXYyOY/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that what you want are all the URLs (what's inside the double-quotes) and not an array full of "window.location" repeated several times:

See working code at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jg36-u109

```
$regex[0] = '/window.location(\.href|\.assign)?\s*=\s*"(.+)"/i';
$regex[1] = '/window.location(\.assign|\.replace)\("(.+)"/i';
$regex[3] = '/(self|top)\.location\s*=\s*"(.+)"/i';

$urls = [];
foreach ($regex as $i => $r) {
    preg_match_all($regex[$i], $str, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[2])) {
        $urls = array_merge($urls, $matches[2]);
    }
}
```

Patterns are different enough that rather than one really really complex regex, I created 3 regexes above.  You can loop through these 3, use `preg_match_all`, grab the contents of the 2nd grouping `(.+)`, and append the results of each to an array, which will have your final result: an array containing all the URLs.

Comment: I have added one more regex to this list. It is to verify the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com" />`. The regEx was `|(?:http-equiv="refresh".*?)?content="\d+;url=(.*?)"(?:.*?http-equiv="refresh")?|i` The problem was, it doesnt apply if there is any space between `content=" 1` or `content="1; url=...` What needs to be changed here

Comment: `\s*` will match zero or more whitespace characters.  I do that before and after the `=` in my 3 regexs above.

Answer (score 0):

Thr `preg_match` function finds the first pattern match, you need to use `preg_match_all`. However, your `window\\.location*` pattern matches `window.locationnnnnnn` like stringsn (the `*` quantifier is set to the `n` char). You need to use `.*` instead of `*` to match any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

So, for the string in the question, you may use

```
$str = 'window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        window.location.assign("http://www.example.com");
        window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
        self.location = "http://www.example.com";
        top.location = "http://www.example.com";
        ';
preg_match_all('~window\.location.*~', $str,$result);
print_r($result);
```

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/ZdNmLh).